# How to dynamically resize an array?

Tags: c#

I have an array with `Length = 3` and with values, for example {1,2,3}.
I need to dynamically resize it.

I know that I can use List or 
Array.Resize(). But I need to know how to implement my own resize method?

Comment: A problem with this is that any references to the old array will not change to reference the new array.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348051(v=vs.110).aspx You can look at the reference source for that and see how they did it, but it should be pretty obvious.

Comment: basically, create a new array

Comment: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/array.cs,71074deaf111c4e3

Comment: Why do you need to implement your own resize method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try the following code. Create new array with new size and copy the old array data to the newly created array.

```
public static Array ResizeArray (Array oldArray, int newSize)
{
    int oldSize = oldArray.Length;
    Type elementType = oldArray.GetType().GetElementType();
    Array newArray = Array.CreateInstance(elementType,newSize);
    int preserveLength = System.Math.Min(oldSize,newSize);
    
    if (preserveLength > 0)
    {
        Array.Copy (oldArray,newArray,preserveLength);
    }

    return newArray;
}
```

Comment: The OP does not want using `Array.Resize` method.

Comment: @FelipeOriani I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

If this is just for practice then do it. but i suggest you use  .Net `Array.Resize()` if you want to use it in your code. usually .Net libraries are best implemented and optimized.

Any way...you can do it with generic method

```
private static void Resize<T>(ref T[] array,int size)
{
    T[] token = array.Take(size).ToArray(); // attempt to take first n elements
    T[] temp = new T[size]; // create new reference
    token.CopyTo(temp, 0); // copy array contents to new array
    array = temp; // change reference
}
```

Note that you cannot do this without parameter `ref`. (The other way is to return array of course)

You may think arrays are passed by reference. thats true. **But the references it self are passed by value**. so whenever you try to change the reference it does not refer to the original array anymore. you can only change the contents. To make this possible you have to use `ref` to directly pass the reference into method.

About the code:

`{1,2,3}` if you resize it to `2` obviously it will remove the last parameter. so you will have `{1,2}`

if you resize it to `4` then it will give the array with new default values. either `null` for reference types or `0` for value types (`false` for Boolean type). here you will have `{1,2,3,0}`

```
int[] array = new[] {1, 2, 3};
Resize(ref array,4);
Console.WriteLine(array.Length); // outputs 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you may look on `Array.Resize` source code before making your own implementation =)
http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/array.cs,71074deaf111c4e3

Answer (score 0):

If you want to resize the array use the build in method Array.Resize().It will be easier and faster.

If you need a dynamically sized data structure, use List for that.
You can always do array.ToList() -> fill the list and do .ToArray() later.

Answer (score -1):

Make an array of the new desired size, copy all items over. Make the variable that referenced your old array reference the new one.

Code from MSDN:

```
public static void Resize<T>(ref T[] array, int newSize) {
    if (newSize < 0) {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("newSize", Environment.GetResourceString("ArgumentOutOfRange_NeedNonNegNum"));
        Contract.Ensures(Contract.ValueAtReturn(out array) != null);
        Contract.Ensures(Contract.ValueAtReturn(out array).Length == newSize);
        Contract.EndContractBlock();

        T[] larray = array;                
        if (larray == null) {
            array = new T[newSize];
            return;
        }

        if (larray.Length != newSize) {
            T[] newArray = new T[newSize];
            Array.Copy(larray, 0, newArray, 0,  larray.Length > newSize? newSize : larray.Length);
            array = newArray;
        }
    }
}
```